# Copying storage data from one Azure account to another and organize into date folders

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage, azcopy

azcopy copy '
[https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer'](https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer%27)
'
[https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer'](https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer%27)
--recursive

The above will copy everything from one storage account to another. My requirement is that data should be organized in the target folder based on the last modified date of the files in the source container. The source container is one big directory with lots of files.

Suppose the files are like this in the source

https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/file1 with last modified date of 2023-12-13

https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/file2 with last modified date of 2023-12-14

https://mysourceaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/file3 with last modified date of 2023-12-15

The target directory should be copied like below and this would involve creating the date path based on the source last modified date.

https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/2023/12/13/file1

https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/2023/12/15/file2

https://mydestinationaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/2023/12/15/file3

Comment: Can you attach some script about your attempts? You need to check the last modified date if the folder doesn't exist with that name (like: 2023) create it, follow it with months and days, and copy the file in it. If exist, just copy the file in it.

Comment: Add more info, hope that helps

Comment: That's fine and I understood it before, but what did you try? SO isn't about writing the complete code for you, it's about providing help when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Copying storage data from one Azure account to another and organize into date folders. You need to use get metadata activity. follow below steps:

1. First create the dataset for the blob storage to use in pipeline.

- First dataset is to get the files from source dataset.
  [image]
- Second dataset is to get the last modified date of particular file. create filename parameter and add it in dataset connection.
  [image]
  [image]
- Third dataset is to create folders on the basis of last modified date in Destination container. create filename, folderpath parameters and add it in dataset connection.
  [image]
  [image]

2. Now create a pipeline and take Get metadata activity to get the list of files from source container here add first dataset we created and `Field list` as **Child items**
   [image]
3. Now take Foreach activity and pass the result of Get metadata activity to Foreach activity with expression `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`.
   [image]
4. Under this Foreach activity take another Get metadata activity to get **lastmodified** date of the file. Here add second dataset we created and add dataset parameter as `@item().name` and `Field list` as **Last modified**
   [image]
5. Now take copy activity to copy data from source to sink with organized folders based on last modified date. Here add second dataset we created in source with dataset parameter as `@item().name` and third dataset we created in sink and with dataset prameter for filename is `@item().name` and folderpath is `@formatDateTime(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified,'yyyy/MM/dd')`
   **-- Source**:
   [image]**--Sink:**
   [image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Pratik !! This uses the ADF.  I was looking performing this using azcopy

Comment: AZ copy will not perform the organization of folder based on date it will just copy file from source to destination.